# Here I am passing a color value from the html page which is not being set by my servlet program

Tags: java, server

From my analysis, the color value is going to the servlet by the response html is not changing its color.

The First File Color.html

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
    <center>
        <h1>RainBow Colors</h1>
        <h2>Choose a color to see Magic</h2>
        <form action="./display" method="GET">
            <B>Color:</B>
            <select name="color" size="2">
            <option value="Violet">Violet</option>
            <option value="Indigo">Indigo</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type=submit value="MAGIC">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

The java Program DisplayColors.java

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DisplayColors extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws 
  ServletException, IOException {
String Color = req.getParameter("color");
PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
pw.println("<p>Color::" + Color + "</p>");
pw.println("<html>");
pw.println("<body bgcolor='Color'>");
pw.println("<marquee><h1>HAVE A GREAT TIME AHEAD</h1></marquee>");
pw.println("</body>");
pw.println("</html>");
pw.close();
}
}
```

The web.xml file from webapps

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DisplayColors</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/display</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Color.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I am running this program on Tomcat9 server localhost. Refer to attached screenshots for more clarity.[image]

The issue here is even if I select green color in the input colors.html, the output color shown is blue or some other color sometimes. Please let me know a technique where servlet will pick the colors properly. There is no problem in passing the data from get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you've probably noticed, the first line in your output HTML prints the right color ("Color: Green").

However, the reason the background is some other funny color (in your case it's blue, my browser shows it in red) is that there's no string concatination happening in the line where the `<body>` tag is output.

Currently: `pw.println("<body bgcolor='Color'>");`

try change it to:  `pw.println("<body bgcolor='"+Color+"'>");`

Background is that in the current code, Java will not treat `Color` as a variable, because it is part of a string. Therefore it just writes out "Color" instead of the contents of the `Color` variable.

The correction shown above leaves the context of the string and glues it together with the actual contents of the variable.

Because "Color" is not an actually acceptable color, you browser will pick whatever it thinks is closest to your input. Whatever that color is - depends on the browser you are using.